# HTACCESS Rewrite seems to keep images and scripts from loading

Tags: image, .htaccess, load

I got this problem and I have been tyring alot (even deleting the htaccess) and I haven't found a solution.

A customer of my company has an application that I didn't make.... but I could nottice that there was an HTACCESS (and it happened to me before) and it seems to have some Rewrite rules. I am not familiar with HTaccess stuff, I am very ignorant about what's going on in this kind of files.

The page looks like this
[image: Images and scripts aren't loading]

### The htaccess file contains this:

```
Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#4 variables
Rewriterule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ $1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9
#3 variables
Rewriterule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ $1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7
#2 variables
Rewriterule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ $1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5
#1 variable
Rewriterule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ $1.php?$2=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

Do you have any idea if that is the HTACCESS FAULT? If I delete the HTACCESS I get a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Sebas The image path is right, because it worked before and those paths haven't been modified, plus I checked. Seems that is the htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a relative/absolute URI issue. The images/scripts/css are probably linked using relative URIs which is broken when you have a structure like this: `(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/`, while it could work fine when you access the page like this: `/$1.php?something`.

So you either need to change all of the links so that they're absolute URLs (that start with a `/`) or create a relative URI base at the header of all of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: I tried commenting the line with the RewriteRule lines and it is still showing missing images... and if I delete the file; it shows an internal server error... this is so weird

Comment: I tried what you said. I put the line <base href="/"> inside my header and it's showing properly!!!